# Enviar E-mail ao apertar um botao

Tags: java, android

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que consiste em, ao apertar um botão um email programado seja enviado automaticamente sem que eu tenha que entrar no gmail para apertar "enviar"

Até então eu montei esse código e ele está fazendo tudo, menos enviar sem que eu tenha que ir até o gmail

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                email.setData(Uri.parse("mailto"));
                email.setType("message/rfc822");
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                        new String[]{"emaildedestinatario@gmail.com"});
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                        "Assunto do email ");
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "mensagem que quero enviar ");
                //startActivity(email);
                email.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_SEND, email);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

o que eu deveria acrescentar para que ele envie sem que tenha que entrar no email

Comment: Ao usar intent, vc estara pedindo para o sistema enviar email, para vc enviar o email programaticamente vc pode usar esse esse tutorial

Comment: https://www.devmedia.com.br/enviando-email-com-javamail-utilizando-gmail/18034